Pass String[] as text[] to NamedNativeQuery in Hibernate 5.6
I have a Postgres function with this signature:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.ums_rate_permissions_for_collection(user_roles_arr text[], profile_id bigint, collection_id bigint)

I access this function via a NamedNativeQuery in Hibernate 5.6, but I'm facing issues passing a String[] as parameters to this method to be used as text[].
The native query:
@NamedNativeQuery(
                name = "getUserRolesPermissionsForCollection",
                query = "SELECT * FROM ums_rate_permissions_for_collection(ARRAY[:profileList], :profileId, :collectionId)"
        )

The DAO:
public UmsRolesNavigationPermissionVO getRolePermissionsForCollection(final List<String> userRoles, final Long profileId, final Long collectionId) {
        String[] param = userRoles.toArray(new String[0]);

        NativeQuery query = this.getSession()
                .getNamedNativeQuery("getUserRolesPermissionsForCollection")
                .setParameterList("profileList", param)
                .setParameter("profileId", profileId)
                .setParameter("collectionId", collectionId);

        List result = query.list();

When I run this query in postgres console, it's working fine:
SELECT * FROM ums_rate_permissions_for_collection(ARRAY['Sales User', 'Admin'], 141, 330)

And also if I only have one element in param, everything is working fine. But as soon as there are 2 or more values in the array, I get these errors:
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2186)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function ums_rate_permissions_for_collection(record[], bigint, bigint) does not exist
  Hinweis: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 15
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
        ... 41 more

So looks like Hibernate is translating this as some sort of record-array instead of text-array. I tried several things, for example, wrapping all individual strings inside '' or transforming my values to a postgres text array representation:
private String convertToPostgresArray(List<String> userRoles) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("'{");
        for (int i = 0; i < userRoles.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(userRoles.get(i));
        }
        sb.append("}'");
        return sb.toString();
    }

The latter approach seems to at least pass a real text[] to Postgres, as the error stack indicates:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AND"
  Wobei: PL/pgSQL function ums_rate_permissions_for_collection(text[],bigint,bigint) line 73 at RETURN QUERY
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
        at org.postgresql@42.2.20//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)
        at deployment.tg-clienta.war//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
        ... 39 more

But nothing really helps. Any ideas?

Colleague of mine gave me the tip that solved this issue. The solution was to use a custom type and add it using the .setParameter(String name, Object value, Type type) method.
String[] param = userRoles.toArray(new String[0]);

NativeQuery query = this.getSession()
                .getNamedNativeQuery("getUserRolesPermissionsForCollection")
                .setParameter("profileList", param, new CustomType(new CustomStringArrayType()))
                .setParameter("profileId", profileId)
                .setParameter("collectionId", collectionId);

With this CustomStringArrayType looking like that:
    public class CustomStringArrayType implements UserType {
        @Override
        public String[] nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner)
                    throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                if (names != null && names.length > 0 && rs != null && rs.getArray(names[0]) != null) {
                    return (String[]) rs.getArray(names[0]).getArray();
                }
                return null;
            }
    }

